# hide/show div from select option on ios - not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone, user-interface

The show/hide div based on select option works well on desktop but not on ios devices. I'm sure there is a better way to structure my jQuery for this requirement. On ios native drop down you can tick all select options and also have to select and de-select in order to see the next option. I need to be able to select one option at a time.

```js
$( function() {
        $( '#storeselector' ).on( 'input propertychange', function() {
            $( '.store-hide' ).hide();
            $( '#' + $(this).val() ).show();
        });
    });
```

```css
.store-right {
  float: right;
}

.i-store {
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-family: "Avenir Next", sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: inherit;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  line-height: 1.2;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 4%;
}

.store-img {
  max-width: 1150px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}

.store-hide {
  display: none;
}

.store-block {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="storeselector" tabindex="2" multiple size="3">
  <option value="level-lg">
    Lower Ground
  </option>
  <option value="level-g">
    Ground Floor
  </option>
  <option value="level-one">
    Level 1
  </option>

</select>

<div id="level-lg" class="store-hide store-block" style="display: block">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <span class="i-store">
                                LG
                            </span>
    <img class="store-img" src="https://www.ctshirts.com/on/demandware.static/-/Sites/default/dw468e879c/UK/SS18/Book6/hp-recs1_UK.jpg" alt="" title="">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="level-g" class="store-hide store-block">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <span class="i-store">
                                G
                            </span>
    <img class="store-img" src="https://www.ctshirts.com/on/demandware.static/-/Sites/default/dwc0f6b72a/UK/SS18/Book6/hp-recs2_UK.jpg" alt="" title="">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="level-one" class="store-hide store-block">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <span class="i-store">
                                1
                            </span>
    <img class="store-img" src="https://www.ctshirts.com/on/demandware.static/-/Sites/default/dwe06b0b29/UK/SS18/Book6/hp-recs3_UK.jpg" alt="" title="">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? As your post looks right now, it will probably just generate a lot of senseless discussion. Could you please be more specific?

Comment: Please edit your question and delete the last comment. That's the right way to do it. When you get some spare time, please take take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `input event` instead of the `change event`. Because the `change event` may not work on all browsers.

The `Change` event fires in most browsers when content is changed and the element loses focus, basically an aggregate of changes. You will not see this fired for every single changed unlike the input event.

The `Input` event fires synchronously on change of the content for the element. So you will see this event occur more often. Browser support varies.

So, `input` event is very useful to track `<select>` fields changes. However it is not supported in `IE version < 9`. But older IE versions has its own proprietary event `onpropertychange` that does the same as `oninput`. So you can use it this way to have a full cross browser support.:

```
$( selector ).on( 'input propertychange' );
```

So, your javascript code must be like this:

```
$( function() {
    $( '#storeselector' ).on( 'input propertychange', function() {
        $( '.store-hide' ).hide();
        $('#storeselector option:selected' ).each( function() {
            $( '#' + $(this).val() ).show();
        } )
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Great suggestion! However this doesn't get around issue on ios. Still have to select and deselect in order to see the next option.

Comment: You must use the JQuery `each()` method. The `each()` method specifies a function to run for each matched element. I update the code. check it please.

Comment: unsuccessful - I still have to deselect previous option and select next option in order to see the next one on IOS